# Randomly assign features a value based on a percentage in QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, advanced-python-field-calculator

I have a large set of buildings, each of which I would like to randomly assign a new value to in field calculator-based on percentages. For example, I'd like 30% of the features to be assigned X, 20% Y, and the last 50% to be Z. I realize I could do this manually, but I am wondering if anyone has any idea how to code this in the field calculator using Python.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the field calculator to add a field with a random integer between `1` and `100`. Then calculate a new field with your label with a `CASE` statement.

Calculate a field called `random`

```sql
rand(1, 100)
```

Then calculate a field called `label`

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN "random" <= 30 THEN 'X'                       -- ~30 % of the randomly generated integers
  WHEN "random" > 30 AND "random" <= 50 THEN 'Y'     -- ~20 %
  ELSE 'Z'                                           -- the remainder
END
```

On a layer with 1000 features:

[image]

---

Alternative expression that skips making the `random` field. Use this directly on the `label` field:

```sql
with_variable('random', rand(1,100),
    CASE 
      WHEN @random <= 30 THEN 'X' 
      WHEN @random > 30 AND @random <= 50 THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'Z'
    END
)
```

Testing the method:

The following table is the result of an equivalent algorithm run in Python. 
Where: 
`n` is the sample size 
`x`, `y`, `z` are the number of times that label was assigned
`pc *` is the corresponding percent

It was run 10 times with `n` being a random integer between `10000` and `20000`.

|  | n | x | y | z | pc x | pc y | pc z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11999 | 3559 | 2418 | 6022 | 29.66 | 20.15 | 50.19 |
| 2 | 15654 | 4696 | 3093 | 7865 | 30 | 19.76 | 50.24 |
| 3 | 12690 | 3736 | 2612 | 6342 | 29.44 | 20.58 | 49.98 |
| 4 | 17386 | 5181 | 3493 | 8712 | 29.8 | 20.09 | 50.11 |
| 5 | 16857 | 5146 | 3320 | 8391 | 30.53 | 19.7 | 49.78 |
| 6 | 12494 | 3753 | 2568 | 6173 | 30.04 | 20.55 | 49.41 |
| 7 | 19436 | 5904 | 3852 | 9680 | 30.38 | 19.82 | 49.8 |
| 8 | 10304 | 3064 | 2099 | 5141 | 29.74 | 20.37 | 49.89 |
| 9 | 12987 | 3873 | 2633 | 6481 | 29.82 | 20.27 | 49.9 |
| 10 | 12778 | 3757 | 2536 | 6485 | 29.4 | 19.85 | 50.75 |

Comment: You can't be sure that the features with `"random" <= 30` are 30% of the total features.

Comment: Indeed, one can't be sure, but it gives a good approximation. See my updated answer. Every feature has a 30 in 100 (30%) chance of being assigned the `X` label.